# Automating Putty via VBExcel

Tags: excel, vba

I would like to automate the following process through Excel VBA:
1. Open Putty particular path
2. Login with Credentials
3. Navigate to a path in the server. ( cd /folder1/folder2)
I am able to to do 1 & 2. As I am new to VBA , I am not  aware as to hw to achieve the 3rd .

Comment: Did you try `Sendkeys`? Maybe if you post the code of the first two steps help will be easier.

Comment: `ChDir "c:\folder1\folder2"`

Comment: Public Sub Test()
Dim PuttyPID as Long
Dim username as String
Dim password as String


username= " xxxxxx"
Password= "123456"

P1 = "C:\Program Files (x86)\PuTTy\putty.exe  - ssh" &  username & "@xx.yyy.zzz.aaa - pw"  & Password

PuttyPID = Shell(pc1, 1)

Comment: This is the code I used to connect and login to Putty which is working fine

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Public Sub Test()
  Dim PuttyPID as Long, username as String, password as String
  username= " xxxxxx": Password= "123456"
  P1 = "C:\Program Files (x86)\PuTTy\putty.exe - ssh" & username & _
    "@xx.yyy.zzz.aaa - pw" & Password
  PuttyPID = Shell(P1, 1)

  '''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
  Application.Wait Now + TimeSerial(0, 0, 20) ' <-- give it time to get server prompt
  AppActivate PuttyPID ' <-- activate it again to make sure
  SendKeys "cd /folder1/folder2" & vbCr ' <-- vbCR to simulate CR key
End Sub
```

Comment: Addition to above code .. I have inserted below command to list out the logs which contains particular text ( eg: abc): 

SendKeys "grep -il abc *.log "

Is there any way I can modify the code to take "abc" value from user rather than providing it in code?

Comment: The agenda is to list out out all the files in the folder2 which has "abc" text in it

Comment: @HarshitNaik you can use `InputBox` to get something from user then compose your string using concatenation. `x = InputBox("enter something") SendKeys "grep -il " & x & "*.log "`

Comment: Addition to the above ... After  performing the " grep -il " & x &"*.log ". I would like to copy the logs listed to be copied from the particular server location to my desktop.how can I achieve it?

Comment: @HarshitNaik That's a real different and much more difficult topic. I suggest that you ask a specific question about it.